# A value which should be judged by a scale gets bad judgement sometimes

Tags: excel, vba

There is a weight measurment which gives us different numbers. But there is always a standard weight for example: 100, so then the Min-Max will be +/- 10%. (90 - 110).

The code's job is to tell if it's OK or NOT.
Like if it's 89.9 then it's NOT GOOD, but if it's 99.2 it should be OK.

Sometimes a problem occur for no reason, because even if it's on the scale it goes NOT GOOD, and sometimes it's outside of the scale and it goes OK.

The code's part where it's important is here; (Not mine code, I just have to fix it somehow)

```
                    If Val(txtWeight.Value) < Val(txtMinWeight.Value) Or Val(txtWeight.Value) > Val(txtMaxWeight.Value) Then
                        lblJudgement.Caption = "NOT GOOD"
                        Sheets("Measurment").Cells(j, 2).Value = "NOT GOOD"
                        lblJudgement.BackColor = 255
                        txtWeight.BackColor = 255
                        Call BadSound
                    Else
                        lblJudgement.Caption = "OK"
                        Sheets("Measurment").Cells(j, 2).Value = "OK"
                        lblJudgement.BackColor = 49152
                        txtWeight.BackColor = 49152
                        Call GoodSound
                    End If
```

As long as I see it, all the formulas, calculations should be good, so I have no clue why does it turns around sometimes and give back wrong judgements.

If any other information is needed, please let me know!

Thank y'all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Val function recognizes only the period ( . ) as a valid decimal separator. When different decimal separators are used, as in international applications, use CDbl instead to convert a string to a number. [Microsoft Val function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It got me through eventually, cause I found out the separator was different in the excel from the required. ( it was comma instead of dot )